# Problem with .saveAll from ReactiveCrudRepository

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, reactive-programming, reactive

I'm working in a project where I need to make a bot to fill a DB, but I'm having a problem with the method `saveAll`, because that can recibe an Iterable or a publisher I'm trying to send a list and sending that to Flux, turning that iterable.
I'm receiving "status": 500,
   "error": "Internal Server Error"
that from the postman, and I was debugging and see the problem in the .saveAll.

```
private Flux<workData> makeWork(int account) {

    List<workData> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < account; i++) {
        list.add(makework(i));
    }

    return workDataRepository.saveAll(Flux.fromIterable(list));
}
```

`makework()` return a type `workData`.

How can I do to .saveAll take that `Flux.fromIterable(list)` like an iterable?

All I need is, that list saved in that repository, but that method need return a type `Flux<workData>`

Comment: The 500 means that you're getting an exception trace on the server's console. Post it.

Comment: (Note also that unless you need to store the list for some other reason, it may be more efficient and is not any more complicated to use a stream, such as `Flux.fromStream(IntStream.range(0, account).mapToObj(this::makeWork))`.)

Comment: Spring Data JPA does not support `ReactiveCrudRepository`. So either you are using something else (Spring Data R2DBC for example) or this might even be the reason for the problems.